# Logo appears pixelized in Chrome , Not Firefox or IE

Tags: css

I am a backend developer and could use some CSS help.

I have a logo that displays pixelized in Chrome only?

Does anyone have any suggestions or a solution for this?

the site is at

https://empowermetamela.com/

Tried changing CSS but breaking the auto resize on scroll down

**CSS**

```
#logo {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
max-height: 54%;
margin-bottom: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); 
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://empowermetamela.com/">                     
  <img src="https://empowermetamela.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/empower-me-tamela-logo.png" alt="Empower Me ~ Tamela" id="logo" data-height-percentage="73" />
</a>
```

Need a logo to Display smooth in Chrome

Comment: remove the max-height and set a width on the anchor and make the image 100% width of that anchor and it should render properly (https://jsfiddle.net/ym0xL7bu/1/), otherwise convert your png to an svg and use that

Comment: It's an hack but try this:     transform: rotate(0deg);

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the issue:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

If it isn't necessary, I'd remove it. If that's not an option, then as Pete mentioned in his comment, this may be a good candidate for an SVG and/or basing its size on width instead of height.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for the #logo img

```
-ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari */
transform: scale(1);
```

Hope it useful to you :)